# Clustered column chart by month when month name is in column title

Tags: powerbi

I have the following table

| Name | Department | Jan-23 | Feb-23 | Mar-23 | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Emp 1 | Dpt1 | 100 | 110 | 100 | 310 |
| Emp 2 | Dpt1 | 090 | 090 | 090 | 270 |
| Emp 3 | Dpt1 | 110 | 110 | 110 | 330 |
| Emp 4 | Dpt2 | 080 | 100 | 080 | 260 |
| Emp 5 | Dpt2 | 200 | 150 | 125 | 475 |
| Emp 6 | Dpt3 | 100 | 110 | 120 | 330 |

Without unpivoting the table, is there a method in Power BI to get a clustered column chart where we have the months on x-axis and the total on y-axis.

An example plot is given below but was generated with another set of data.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Without unpivoting the table, is there a method in Power BI to get a clustered column chart where we have the months on x-axis and the total on y-axis.

No.  You must fix the data model.  Power BI is a data modeling tool first, and a visualization tool second.

Comment: Thank you. I unpivoted it and got the desired result.